# Trying to generate a sine wave '.wav' file in Python. Comes out as a square wave

Tags: python, audio, wav, wave

I have the following code, which I expect should generate me a nice sounding 200 Hz sine .wav file.

```
import wave
import numpy as np
import sys

def parse_to_byte(int_data):
    byte_list = []
    for x in int_data:
        byteified_int = x.to_bytes(3, byteorder=sys.byteorder, signed=False)
        byte_list.append(byteified_int)
    return byte_list

def create_wave(channels, samprate, sampwidth, signal):
    bytified_data = parse_to_byte(signal)
    with wave.open('output.wav', 'wb') as newwave:
        newwave.setnchannels(channels)
        newwave.setsampwidth(sampwidth)
        newwave.setframerate(samprate)
        i=0
        for x in bytified_data:
            newwave.writeframes(x)
        newwave.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 44100*4 # Sample count
    fs = 44100 # Sampling rate
    st = 1.0 / fs # Sample time
    t = np.arange(N) * st # Time vector

    nchannels = 1
    sampwidth = 3

    signal2 = 8388607*np.sin(2*np.pi * 200*t)
    signal2 = [ int(x)+8388608 for x in signal2 ]

    create_wave(nchannels, fs, sampwidth, signal2)
```

I'm hugely confused, because the code generates a sound, which matches a 200 Hz square wave, but when I reopen the wave file, and parse the bytes to an array of integers, and plot, it looks like a 200 Hz sine wave.  I would greatly appreciate any insight.

I've already tried:

1. changing the byteorder to 'big'
2. changing sample width (or byte depth) to 2 (and reducing signal2's magnitude to compensate)

Ref: 200 Hz sine wave: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bcrICDkuXw&t=2s
Ref: 200 Hz square wave: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2SOOorT2Ko&t=6s

Comment: it helps to plot the raw audio PCM data ... also shorten the time to say one tenth of a second not 4 seconds as it makes visualizing the curve easier

Comment: @ScottStensland I have it plotted on my machine, but for the sake of clarity, I included only necessary code chunks.  I'm suspicious that its something to do with the 'create wave' function, particularly newwave.writeframes(x)